# AWS s3 x-amz-website-redirect-location not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I created a bucket in s3.  Static website hosting, choose Enable. I upload two html file.

page1.html

```
This is page1
```

page2.html

```
This is page2
```

I added metadata x-amz-website-redirect-location = /page2.html into page1 object in s3 website console.

When I visit http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com/page1.html on chrome. it's not redirect(it's page1 content not page2).  I followed the documentation and search about this question.   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/how-to-page-redirect.html

thanks in advance.

screenshot of page1 metadata
[image]

My bucket settings.
[image]

curl -v the site

```
$ curl -v  https://aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/page1.html
*   Trying 3.5.154.185...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com (3.5.154.185) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Dec  9 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  2 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /page1.html HTTP/1.1
> Host: aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< x-amz-id-2: jWBm/e0Rdb2BB3R/nFffH8/YS2+f1AgXFHQfT6bUzmMK9tMZDtSNYprUp4Ka6m9xMKookshlWwo=
< x-amz-request-id: T4JG7K11X2FTBCA8
< Date: Thu, 09 Jun 2022 02:15:03 GMT
< Last-Modified: Thu, 09 Jun 2022 02:12:42 GMT
< ETag: "a12ac1ca5226842e56871deaa4d9ef9c"
< x-amz-website-redirect-location: /page2.html
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Content-Type: text/html
< Server: AmazonS3
< Content-Length: 14
<
This is page1
* Connection #0 to host aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of the metadata that you added?

Comment: @jellycsc Sure. I post it

Comment: I tested your setup and it works perfectly. Could you post the output of the following command? `curl -v http://bucket-name.s3-website.Region.amazonaws.com/page1.html`

Comment: @jellycsc I have posted it. It print page1 not page2.  We verify it. curl https://aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/page2.html.

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the website endpoint. I tested the following url and it works.

http://aws-redirect-test.s3-website-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/page1.html

Answer (score 0):

For others experiencing this issue:

When using the raw bucket endpoint (https://aws-redirect-test.s3.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/page1.html in your example), you can see the `x-amz-website-redirect-location` header being returned, but you need to use the URL with `-website` in it to use any of the static hosting features including redirects.

Unfortunately we couldn't do this since we had already shared links to the "raw" URLs for some objects. What we ended up doing instead:

- rename the object from `file.pdf` to `file.old.pdf`
- upload a new HTML file as `file.pdf` and set `Content-Type: text/html` in the S3 metadata settings
- the HTML file contains a redirect like `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/file.pdf" />` (and a link to the new location, and a JavaScript redirect for good measure)

Ugly, but I don't think a better solution is possible if you have already shared the raw URL to an object.